# How do I use a Firebase Hosting SSL Certificate for AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, firebase-hosting

I'm hosting my app via `firebase` at `www.example.com`

I have several `AWS Lambda` functions with `AWS API Gateway` endpoints.  [According to the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html), to call my `lambda` functions via a subdomain on my `example.com` domain, I need a "PEM-encoded SSL certificate".

I'm assuming I shouldn't/don't have to create a new SSL certificate for this purpose, but I'm unclear how to proceed.

Can I obtain the required fields (certificate `body`, certificate `chain`, & `private key`) for my `Firebase hosting` SSL cert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. Firebase Hosting provisions an SSL certificate on your behalf, but the private key used to generate that certificate belongs solely to Firebase and cannot be shared or downloaded. To get an SSL certificate for other services, you will need to purchase one or generate one through [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).